# Samsung Galaxy Ace Internet Connection Problems

Tags: connection-issues, internet, samsung-galaxy-ace

My mother owns a Samsung Galaxy Ace(GT-S5830) mobile phone and we have a wireless modem from Airties with model number Air5343 broadcasting its SSID. The wireless works fine with all devices except Linux Mint 16 which has hard time connnecting automatically. The mobile phone recognized the broadcasted SSID but is unable to connect to it. The network uses WPA2 encryption with a password of 10 characters of length. The phone used to connect to the modem but the modem has been replaced two times. How can I make the phone connected to the home network?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried letting the phone forget the Wi-Fi password, and setting it again? [not sure if this will help though]

Comment: @geffchang Yes, I have tried it but it did not work.